# Some concepts in Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection

I am new to dependency injection and have been doing some reading about it, both on StackOverflow and elsewhere. In practice I am having trouble with using it correctly.

To explain the problem, here's a basic situation where I am not sure how to use DI:
Suppose I have some object that is going to be used in several different classes. However, in order for this object to be usable, it needs certain parameters that I don't have at start-up.

A conceivable way that I can see to do this using DI is to create a blank instance of this object, a method to initialize it with the necessary parameters, and a flag for whether or not it is initialized.

To me, this feels like a hack, because the object shouldn't really exist yet and I am just passing a container around, waiting for the responsible code to initialize it. Is this how it is meant to be done, or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed a pretty tough thing to get one's head around when getting started with DI, and something that also isn't easily explained.

Your notion that creating a "blank" object that will be initialized later via a method might be a suboptimal solution is correct - an object should be able to do its work at any time; `Initialize()` methods are what Mark Seemann calls "temporal coupling" in his book *Dependency Injection in .NET*. This is an anti-pattern that makes the code using the object dependent on the inner workings of that object and thus breaks encapsulation.

The question is when the required information becomes available, what the "responsible code to initialize it" is, and where it gets the information from - and also how it gets access to the object to initialize it. Ideally, this initializing code would itself be injected into your object, and whenever your object's methods/properties are accessed, it requests initialization from that other dependency.

Also, what happens if the `IsInitialized` flag returns false? Is that still a valid program state?

In general, as an object in a dependency injected object graph, I should either know all my "configuration" data on creation, or know someone who can give it to me (that someone is another object injected as a dependency).

It might help if you could provide a bit more detail about what kind of parameters the object needs and where they need to come from.

**Edit**

What you're describing in your comment is pretty much exactly my first encounter with this kind of issue; there's a question somewhere here on SO that I posted back then.

The important thing is to build individual classes (usually, there may be exceptions, but what those are is a matter of experience) in such a way that you assume everything the class needs is present. When the program is running, there need to be other classes then that make sure that assumption will not fail.

Setter injection is something I generally try not to have to avoid said temporal coupling; according to Mark Seemann, setter injection should usually only be used when you already have a good default in place that you just overwrite through the setter. In this case, though, the object would not be able to function properly without that dependency.

This may not be the most elegant way to do this (I usually have the luxury to apply DI in pretty closed code-only environments without having to worry about a UI), but it would work (kind of - it compiles, but is still pseudo code):

```cs
public class MainForm
{
    private readonly IDataManager _dataManager;
    private readonly IConnectionProvider _connectionProvider;
    private readonly IConnectionReceiver _connectionReceiver;

    public MainForm(IDataManager dataManager, IConnectionProvider connectionProvider, IConnectionReceiver connectionReceiver)
    {
        this._dataManager = dataManager;
        this._connectionProvider = connectionProvider;
        this._connectionReceiver = connectionReceiver;
    }

    public void btnConnect_Click()
    {
        IConnection connection = this._connectionProvider.GetConnection();

        if (null != connection)
        {
            this._connectionReceiver.SetConnection(connection);

            this.SetFormControlsEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void SetFormControlsEnabled(bool doEnable)
    {
    }
}

public interface IConnectionProvider
{
    IConnection GetConnection();
}

public interface IConnectionReceiver
{
    void SetConnection(IConnection connection);
}

public interface IConnection
{
    IConnectionWebService ConnectionWebService { get; }
}

public class ConnectionBridge : IConnection, IConnectionReceiver
{
    private IConnection _connection;

    #region IConnectionReceiver Members

    public void SetConnection(IConnection connection)
    {
        this._connection = connection;
    }

    #endregion IConnectionReceiver Members

    #region IConnection Members

    public IConnectionWebService ConnectionWebService
    {
        get { return this._connection.ConnectionWebService; }
    }

    #endregion
}

public interface IConnectionWebService {}

public interface IDataManager { }

public class DataManager : IDataManager
{
    public DataManager(IConnection connection)
    {
    }
}
```

So, `MainForm` is the thing that holds it all together. It starts out with its controls disabled, because it knows they need a working `IDataManager` and that will (by convention) need a connection. When a "connect" button is clicked, the form asks its `IConnectionProvider` dependency for a connection. It does not care where that connection comes from; the connection provider might display another form to ask for credentials or maybe just read them from a file.

Then the form knows that the connection has to be passed on to the `IConnectionReceiver` instance, and after that all controls can be enabled. This is not by any DI principle, this is just how we have defined that `MainForm` works.

The data manager on the other hand has everything it needs from the start - an `IConnection` instance. That can't do what it's supposed to do at first, but there is other code preventing that from causing problems.

`ConnectionBridge` is both a decorator for the actual `IConnection` instance and an adapter decoupling connection acquisition from connection consumption. It does that by employing the *Interface Segregation Principle*.

As a note on the side, be aware that while Dependency Injection is an important technique, it is only one of several principles you should follow to write what is known as "clean code". The most well known are the *SOLID* principles (of which DI is one), but there are others like *Command-Query-Separation (CQS)*, *"Don't repeat yourself" (DRY)* and the *Law of Demeter*. On top of all that, practice unit testing, precisely *Test Driven Development (TDD)*. These things really make a tremendous difference - but if you're taking up DI of your own accord, you're already off to a good start.

Comment: Actually I think I'm missing something much more basic. To give you a more specific (and basic) example: In a basic forms application, suppose I have a window where a user enters some credentials. Now, let's say I have a DataManager which needs the credentials to Connect. Once the user hits Connect, he is taken to the main Window where he can use this DataManager for whatever. How does the flow look like with DI in this type of situation?

Comment: A quick addition: I realize that in this particular example there are other ways to solve the problem. But it does show the problem: without adding any other layer for simplicity we have classes for the 2 forms, as well as the DataManager. The second form opens from the first form so the first form needs an instance of the DataManager and the 2nd Form, in the constructor. We can use setter injection on the 2nd form before showing it, but is there a way to do this through constructor injection only.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I will implement something similar to get a feel for it to get a better feel for it. As for coding practices it's actually because of how difficult unit testing is of non-DI code that I decided to try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what GCATNM said and i would like to add that whenever i feel there is an object like this i go and use one of the Factory pattern variants (be it an Abstract Factory, Static Factory, etc ..) and i would inject the factory with the source of the configuration information for this object. So as Marc Seemann also said and i am not quoting: Factories are a great companion of Dependency Injection and you will need them occasionally.

Comment: There's a good chance that the solution is going to be an Abstract Factory, yeah, but not necessarily so. There's too little information at this point; might as well end up with some kind of Adapter pattern.